# Does exists some console utility for keyboard layout switching in Mac OS X?

Tags: keyboard, console

For example, there is `xkb-switch` on Linux. Is there some analog in Mac OS X? I googled but found nothing. Yes I know about AppleScript but it doesn't fit to my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I wrote it myself.
If you need one see code of utility here (https://github.com/myshov/xkbswitch-macosx) if you want in `bin` directory there is already compiled version.